# $ \sum _{k=3}^n\:\left(\frac{k!}{\left(k-3\right)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}\right) $

Tags: permutations, combinations

$$ \sum _{k=3}^n\:\left(\frac{k!}{\left(k-3\right)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}\right) $$

I should write this in a simplified form, using the formulas of Combinations $\ (\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!})$ and Arrangements $\ (\frac{n!}{(n-k)!})$ and I don't seem to find anything... The correct answer is $\ \frac{n!}{(n-3)!}*2^{n-3}  $. How should I approach such an exercise? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$a_k:=\frac{k!}{\left(k-3\right)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{k!\left(n-k\right)!}.$$
First, simplify the $k!$ to get 
$$a_k=\frac{n!}{\left(k-3\right)!\cdot \left(n-k\right)!}.$$
Then write $  \left(n-k\right)!= \left((n-3)-(k-3)\right)!$. This shows that 
$$a_k=\frac{n!}{(n-3)!} \binom{n-3}{k-3} .$$
If you plug this into the sum you get:
$$\frac{n!}{(n-3)!} \sum \limits_{k=3}^{n}\binom{n-3}{k-3} = \frac{n!}{(n-3)!} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3}{k}  = \frac{n!}{(n-3)!} \cdot 2^{n-3}$$